# store zeros after decimal point in variable in c#

Tags: c#

my application in c# is on payroll management system...and i would like to have the work hours of each employee in variable ...for this i m using double ...suppose an employee works for 8 hours and 20 min ..then the entry will be like 8.20 in text box...so i am separating the part before decimal in one variable using`

```
var values = totaldays.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split('.');
int firstno = int.Parse(values[0]);
int secondno = int.Parse(values[1]);`
```

so i m getting first variable accurately but if part after decimal contains zeros it not storing in "secondno" variable . the zeros get eliminated automatically and the result for 8.20 and 8.2 is same i.e., 8.2 .

but since the time is different one is 8 hours 20min and other is 8 hours 2min ..i want some solution to to do this ..please help me since my whole application is dependent on this.

Comment: Don't use a double for the user entry - either use a string or have two text boxes for the hours and minutes.

Comment: Might I suggest TimeSpan? You're trying to use a double in a way that will likely end badly in more ways than just what you are encountering now. If someone has worked 8 hours and 30 minutes, and then you want to add another 40 minutes on top of that, you'll end up with a value of 8.7, which makes absolutely no sense as a time.

Comment: I suggest you consult your fourth grade arithmetic textbook and review decimals and fractions. A lack of such basic understanding will make programming almost impossible for you.  For writing payroll applications, it's almost scary...

Answer (score 7):

If the user is entering hours and minutes, why not use a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)?

```
var input = "8.20";
var time = TimeSpan.ParseExact(input, @"h\.mm", null);
var hours = time.Hours;      // 8
var minutes = time.Minutes;  // 20
```

**Further Reading**

- [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx)

---

If you really must store it as a decimal first, you can still manage using this:

```
var input = 8.20m;
var parts = input.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split('.');
var hours = int.Parse(parts[0]);     // 8
var minutes =  int.Parse(parts[1]);  // 20
```

But as *Ellesedil* [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598295/store-zeros-after-decimal-point-in-variable-in-c-sharp#comment25611825_17598295), you'll have to decide how to handle values like `8.70`.

Comment: While this doesn't answer the actual question, this is the way it should be done.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. This is off the top of my head:

```
int hours = Math.Floor(totaldays);
int minutes = (totaldays - Math.Floor(totaldays)) * 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just format double with f2 format specifier

```
double d = 8.20;
string str = d.ToString("f2", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
int hour = int.Parse(str.Split('.')[0]);
int min = int.Parse(str.Split('.')[1]);
```

thats it you are done